# How do I convert only the alphabets in a long string to corresponding number of the alphabet, separated with space

Tags: javascript, string

I am doing an homework. And I need to convert a long string to corresponding number of the alphabet e.g. a=1,...,z=26.
I need the functions to ignore any other thing apart from the alphabet i.e should not return it.

**Example**
alphabetPosition("The sunset sets at twelve o' clock.")

Should return "20 8 5 19 21 14 19 5 20 19 5 20 19 1 20 20 23 5 12 22 5 15 3 12 15 3 11" (as a string).

I tried writing this and kept getting errors. I'm not even sure what i'm doing.

```
function alphabetPosition(text) {
  var convertText = text.toLowerCase();
  var anum = {
    a: "1",
    b: "2",
    c: "3",
    d: "4",
    e: "5",
    f: "6",
    g: "7",
    h: "8",
    i: "9",
    j: "10",
    k: "11",
    l: "12",
    m: "13",
    n: "14",
    o: "15",
    p: "16",
    q: "17",
    r: "18",
    s: "19",
    t: "20",
    u: "21",
    v: "22",
    w: "23",
    x: "24",
    y: "25",
    z: "26"
  }
  var arrayText = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < convertText.length - 1; i++) {
    var alpha = convertText.charAt(i);
    if (alpha.match(/[a-z]/i)) {
      var add = anum[alpha] + " ";
      arrayText += add;
    }
  }
  return arrayText;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function alphabetPosition(text) {
var convertText=text.toLowerCase().replace(/[^a-z]/g, '');
var res=[]
for(i=0; i<convertText.length;i++)
 res.push(convertText[i].charCodeAt() - 96)
return res.toString().replace(/,/g,' ')
}
alphabetPosition("How are you doing today?")
```

This is a simple way to do it too.

Answer (score 1):

First replace all non-alphabetical characters with the empty string, transform the alphabetical string into an array. After that, you can use `Array.prototype.map` to transform each character into its character code (starting at a = 1):

```js
const alphabetPosition = (str) => {
  const lowerAlphabeticalString = str
    .toLowerCase()
    .replace(/[^a-z]/g, '');   // replace all non-alphabetical characters
  return [...lowerAlphabeticalString]  // turn the string into an array
    .map(char => char.charCodeAt() - 96) // transform each character into its code
    .join(' '); // join the array by spaces so it becomes a string again
};

console.log(alphabetPosition("The sunset sets at twelve o' clock."));
```

The `- 96` is there because the character code of `a` is 97, the character code of `b` is 98, and so on - so, to get `a` to correspond to `1` and `b` to correspond to 2, subtract by 96.

You could also do this with a single regular expression if you wanted, but it's not so readable:

```js
const alphabetPosition = (str) => str.replace(
  /[^a-z]*([a-z])[^a-z]*/gi,
  (_, char) => (char.toLowerCase().charCodeAt() - 96) + ' '
).trim(); // remove trailing space created by last replacement

console.log(alphabetPosition("The sunset sets at twelve o' clock."));
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll try this now and get back

Comment: What do you mean? You need to define an argument for the array element (the character) so that it can be transformed into a character code

Comment: Thanks. Really appreciate it.